# How to get CSS classes with a backend bean method

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I need to execute some backend methods based on CSS classes of `<html>` or `<body>`.

To determine if the `<html>` tag has a CSS class name `"someClass"` I used JQuery `$("html").hasClass("someClass")`. Then I wrapped it in a function with return values

```
function hasSomeClass() {
    if ($("html").hasClass("someClass")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then I executed my function in my controller via
`RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("hasSomeClass();");`. But 
`RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute()`'s return type if void.

**Q: How can I send the return value of my javascript function to my backend bean function?**

I can think of some options, but I would like to pass the return value as parameter to my backend method directly instead of these walkarounds:

1. Use a global javascript variable as parameter
2. Use a hidden input field

Edit:
About other solutions:

I also tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20458811/8008426), but I don't know where to put `remoteCommandFunctionName([{name: 'name1', value: 'value1'}, {name: 'name2', value: 'value2'}]);`. Do I put it in the `<script>` tag? Do I wrap it with a `function`? Because if I `System.out.println(name1);` I receive `null`.

My quick fix with weird behaviour:

`<h:body onload="hasSomeClass() ? #{controller.onDoSomething('true')} : #{Controller.onDoSomething('false')}" >` returns `true` and `false` a millisecond apart, although `<html>` has `someClass`.

Comment: Try p:remoteCommand which allows you to call a backing bean method from JavaScript: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml

Comment: Your approach is wrong. You're mixing view representation with logic. Why are you trying to get `html`'s css class from a bean? It would be better to call an action instead when some event occur...

Comment: My goal is to get the screen width on load and whenever the window is resized. I want this information to be passed to the backend to determine whether the device is a mobile device or not, because I need this for `rendered="#{controller.mobileView}"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to invoke a JSF managed bean on a HTML DOM event using native JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588327/how-to-invoke-a-jsf-managed-bean-on-a-html-dom-event-using-native-javascript)

Comment: If you found the solution, instead of editing and adding it into the question it would be better to post and accept it as answer. This way it's obvious to anyone that this case is solved.

Answer (score 0):

My solution that works in my use case

```
<script>
function hasSomeClass() {
    if ($("html").hasClass("someClass")) {
        someFunc();
    } else {
        someOtherFunc();
    }
}
</script>

<h:body>
<p:remoteCommand name="someFunc" actionListener="#{controller.soSomething('true case')}"/>
<p:remoteCommand name="someOtherFunc" actionListener="#{controller.soSomething('false case')}"/>
</h:body>
```

Comment: You can pass parameters to the remoteCommand so you only need one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221495/pass-parameter-to-premotecommand-from-javascript