# Invoking a p:remoteCommand via a JavaScript function passing a message local to that function to another function through the "oncomplete" handler

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, parameter-passing, remotecommand

This question is purely based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28793083/1391249) previously asked question ([courtesy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26323226/1391249)) but the question is messed up completely with the Java EE 7 WebSockets API attempting to show the actual practical approach/scenario which is now very unlikely to receive any answer based on `<p:remoteCommand>`.

---

Given below a snippet of JavaScript (this is only a test scenario).

```javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
        var message = "myMessage";
        window["myFunction"]();
        // This is literally interpreted as a JavaScript function "myFunction()".
        // "myFunction()" in turn is associated with a <p:remoteCommand>.
    }

    $(document).ready(test);

    function notifyAll() {
        alert("notifyAll() invoked.");
    }
</script>
```

The `test()` function is invoked as soon as the page is loaded which causes the following [`<p:remoteCommand>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml) to trigger which in turn invokes another JavaScript function, namely `notifyAll()`, using an `oncomplete` handler that simply alerts the said message.

```
<h:form>
    <p:remoteCommand process="@this"
                     name="myFunction"
                     actionListener="#{bean.listener}"
                     oncomplete="notifyAll()"
                     ignoreAutoUpdate="true"/>
</h:form>
```

Assume that the local JavaScript variable `message` inside the `test()` function is assigned a JSON message which is asynchronously received through a WebSockets channel.

<sub>The `notifyAll()` function in turn has to send a notification message (`myMessage` local to the `test()` function - actually a JSON message which is received previously in the `test()` function) to another WebSockets channel which is completely ignored in this question for brevity.</sub>

---

Is it possible to pass the value of `var message = "myMessage"` local to the `test()` function to another function `notifyAll()` through the `oncomplete` handler of the given `<p:remoteCommand>`?

<sub>Declaring `message` as a global JavaScript variable may overwhelm the functionality of WebSockets as the message is received **asynchronously** i.e. a new message may be received while the processing of `<p:remoteCommand>` is still going on/awaiting to complete. Thus, declaring `message` as a global JavaScript variable is not an option.</sub>

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not seeing a better way than [passing it as a parameter into the `<p:remoteCommand>` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18510102) and having the `oncomplete` function extract from it.

```
function test() {
    var message = "myMessage";
    myFunction([{name: "message", value: message}]);
}

function notifyAll(data) {
    var message = decodeURIComponent(data.match(/&message=([^&]*)/)[1]);
    // ...
}
```

```
<p:remoteCommand name="myFunction" ... oncomplete="notifyAll(this.data)" />
```

The `data` argument is already injected in the JS function scope by `oncomplete` and it represents the XHR query string. The regex extracts the parameter from it. Note that the regex assumes that the parameter is never in the beginning of the query string, which is true as it always starts with JSF/PF specific parameters, so it can be kept simple (JS regex is tricky with negative lookbehind).

Comment: Where is `data` coming from? I am getting `undefined`.

Comment: Receiving `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined`. The generated script looks like : `<script>myFunction = function() {PrimeFaces.ab({s:"j_idt5:j_idt6",f:"j_idt5",p:"j_idt5:j_idt6",iau:true,onco:function(xhr,status,args){notifyAll(data);},pa:arguments[0]});}</script>`.

Comment: Sorry, you should pass in `this.data`.