# Reload page from backing bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, reload

In my code, I'm expanding treeNode in left frame that is selected through navigation links present in right frame. It works but everytime I click the link on right frame, I have to refresh the right frame manually. I tried to reload the page from backing bean using javascript code but it's not working. Can anyone please help me to figure out why it's not getting executed.

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Below is the code I'm using.

```
public void expandTreeView( TreeNode selectedNode )
{
    if ( selectedNode != null )
    {
        selectedNode.getParent().setExpanded( true );

    }
    RequestContext rc = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    rc.execute("window.location.reload(true)");

}
```

Comment: when you click on the right frame (the treetable) you want to change the left frame content ?!?

Comment: Yes, on clicking on a link in right frame, I want to select the corresponding treeNode and expand the treeNode in left frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine a JS Function with remoteCommand, it will look like this :

***myHTML.xhtml***

```
<p:commandLink id="commandLink" onclick="myFunction(nodeSelected)"  >
...
</p:commandLink>
```

Also add a JS function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function myFunction(x) {                                
       ...                                
    }    
</script>
```

and finally combine it with a `p:remoteCommand` it allows you to call a managedBean method from your JS function

You can see [Primefaces remoteCommand Example](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml) or simply look to this SO post [Invoking a p:remoteCommand via a JavaScript function passing a message local to that function to another function through the “oncomplete” handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32377522/invoking-a-premotecommand-via-a-javascript-function-passing-a-message-local-to)

Hope that helped you.

Comment: It did not work for me. I already tried that before. I'm not selecting, expanding any node directly, that's why I think these ajax events are not working.

Comment: Yes, I'm using commandLink in right frame. The value attribute in command link is set in backing bean. It selects the value from tree.

Comment: There are a lot of commandLinks, I need to put onclick attribute manually in all of them and write myFunction(x) in all the pages this way. Is this the only way?

Comment: non you can put it in an include page (it's kind of a template) and use it every where reade this post [Include Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926106/primefaces-rendered-attribute-impact-on-performance/42930436#42930436) and why not upvote it ;)