# PrimeFaces remoteCommand won't trigger in an error page

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jboss

Why does p:remoteCommand does not trigger when I try calling it in an error page but it works if I removed it as an error-page. Am I missing a configuration?

web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/errorPage.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

errorPage.xhtml

```
<h:form>
    <p:remoteCommand name="rCom1" actionListener="#{bean.method}" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: move it before the form and see what's hapening. and read my complet example [How does remoteCommand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871125/reload-page-from-backing-bean/42883667#42883667)

Comment: moving the remoteCommand will cause jsf to throw a FacesException that rCom1 must be inside the form.