# Listening to variable changes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

```javascript
function notify() {
    var json = {
        'sessionId': "#{session.id}",
        'cartToken': "#{socketTokenBean.token}"
    };

    notifyAll(JSON.stringify(json)); // Push "json" to a WebSocket channel.
}
```

```xhtml
<p:inputText value="#{bean.value}" .../>
<p:commandButton value="Submit" oncomplete="notify()" process="@this" update="..." .../>
```

There could be another component like `<p:selectOneMenu>` in place of `<p:inputText>`. Consider it as an input component holding a quantity value in a shopping basket. `bean` is a session scoped managed bean holding a list of items in a shopping basket.

The `oncomplete` handler of `<p:commandButton>` invokes a JavaScript function which pushes a JSON message to a WebSocket channel. Obviously, if nothing is changed in `<p:inputText>`, pushing a JSON message to a WebSocket channel is worth nothing - it will unnecessarily send associated clients a notification taking unnecessary processing power.

Is there a way to invoke the `notify()` function here `oncomplete="notify()"`, only if the value held by the given `<p:inputText>` has been changed?

Comment: Wouldn't you rather do it server side with JSF `ValueChangeListener`?

Comment: But how? It would not prevent the JavaScript function `notify()` from being invoked which when invoked pushes a JSON message to a WebSocket channel which in turn notifies associated clients quite unnecessarily.

Comment: If the form is submitted, value change listeners will run (you can programmatically add them if necessary) and in action/prerender you could determine if anything is changed and then trigger the push just from server side on. This way there's no need for `notifyAll()` (I have a deja vu on this function name, perhaps you've previously asked a simliar question?)

Comment: @BalusC: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32426674/notify-only-specific-users-through-websockets-when-something-is-modified-in-t

Comment: @Kukeltje: no this one http://stackoverflow.com/q/28793083

Comment: @BalusC: that was the one I was indeed looking for, but my oh my, I could not find it (::shame::)