# Primefaces p:remoteCommand parameter always null

Tags: primefaces, remotecommand

I am trying to pass a parameters with

> p:remoteCommand

Unfortunately when I retrieve the paramer in my bean method I always get null.

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Here is my page code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="rc([{'d':'01'}])">01</a>

<p:remoteCommand name="rc" update=":myform:messages" actionListener="#{mybean.changedaybar}" />
```

and this is the bean method:

```
public void changedaybar() {
            Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
            String param = params.get("d");

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Executed"+param, "Using RemoteCommand."));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which PrimeFaces version are you using? It's important because the way to pass parameters from a JavaScript function to a `p:remoteCommand` has changed in PrimeFaces 3.3.

You will see the correct syntax in the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18510102/2118909 but for your convenience here is the summary.

From PrimeFaces 3.3

> **Passing Parameters**
>
> Remote command can send dynamic parameters in the following way;
>
> `increment([{name:'x', value:10}, {name:'y', value:20}]);`

```
<a href="#" onclick="rc([{name: 'd', value:'01'}])">01</a>
```

Before PrimeFaces 3.3

> **Passing Parameters**
>
> Remote command can send dynamic parameters in the following way;
>
> `increment({param1:'val1', param2:'val2'});`

```
<a href="#" onclick="rc({d:'01'})">01</a>
```

Comment: I am using 5.2. Anyway your example was useful.

Comment: Please just mark it as a duplicate if it is...

Comment: I don't think it is. My question was referrred to a particular case. The answered really helped me contrary to the other one, which I had seen but didn't find useful.

Comment: Hmmmm imo it contians all relevant information. Maybe you did not understand the relation. As posted in the answer, it is a summary of that other post, but yes in the context of your question.