# primefaces password control with press enter to call webflow function

Tags: javascript, ajax, primefaces

I have below code. Want to call spring webflow function and then controller function through "selectAllEssie3S1_1" when press enter key in password field. But I find that the function was not called when debugging. Is there anything wrong??

```
<p:password id="encryptedKey" value="#{chkTeacherList.encryptedKeyValue}" 
onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { onchange(); return false; }">
<p:ajax event="change" action="selectAllEssie3S1_1" update="gridItemName" >
</p:ajax>
</p:password>
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this code maybe can help you

```
<p:remoteCommand name="test" actionListener="#{chkTeacherList.test}"/>
<p:password id="encryptedKey" value="#{chkTeacherList.encryptedKeyValue}"
  onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { test(); return false; }"/>
and in backing bean:

public void test() {
 System.out.println("Pressed enter! value :"+encryptedKeyValue);
}
```

Comment: I need to pass parameters to controller function e.g. statusBean.test(RequestContext...)

Comment: yo can pass parameters to remoteCommand  take a look at this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221495/pass-parameter-to-premotecommand-from-javascript    but if you wanna retrieve some value from bean take directly at bean method

Comment: and if you want to connect remoteCommand directly with springwebflow try adding action property with transition name

Comment: It is Worlking. Thanks