# <p:ajax> Event:select is not supported inside a p:pickList

Tags: jsf, events, primefaces, picklist

When I want to catch select and unselect event in a PrimeFaces 4.0 `p:pickList` I got an error `<p:ajax> Event:select is not supported.`

```
<p:pickList  showCheckbox="true" id="pickList"  value="#{ctrl.elts}" var="elt" itemLabel="#{elt}" itemValue="#{elts}" >
    <f:facet name="sourceCaption">A</f:facet>
    <f:facet name="targetCaption">B</f:facet>

    <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{ctrl.select}"  />
    <p:ajax event="unselect" listener="#{ctrl.onUnselect}" />
</p:pickList>
```

```
public class ctrl implements Serializable {
public void select(SelectEvent event) {
     System.out.println(event.getObject().toString());
}

public void onUnselect(UnselectEvent event) {
     System.out.println(event.getObject().toString());
}
```

...

So, I am wondering how to know which Items is checked if I can't use Select and unSelect event ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In Primefaces 4 pickList has transfer event only, the select/unselect events have been added in Primefaces 5.2

From the docs:

**Ajax Behavior Events**

> PickList provides transfer as the default and only ajax behavior event
>   that is fired when an item is moved from one list to the other.
>   Example below demonstrates how to use this event.

```
<p:pickList value="#{pickListBean.cities}" var="city"
         itemLabel="#{city}" itemValue="#{city}">
    <p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{pickListBean.handleTransfer}" />
</p:pickList>
```

---

```
public class PickListBean {
    //DualListModel code
    public void handleTransfer(TransferEvent event) {
             //event.getItems() : List of items transferred
             //event.isAdd() : Is transfer from source to target
             //event.isRemove() : Is transfer from target to source     
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To catch the select/unselect event you can bind to checkboxes click event

```
<p:pickList widgetVar="pick" showCheckbox="true" id="pickList"  value="#{ctrl.elts}" var="elt" itemLabel="#{elt}" itemValue="#{elts}" >
    <f:facet name="sourceCaption">A</f:facet>
    <f:facet name="targetCaption">B</f:facet>
</p:pickList>

<script>
    $(function(){
        PF('pick').checkboxes.each(function(){
            $(this).bind("click", function(){
                var checked = $(this).find("> span.ui-icon-check").length > 0
                if ( checked ){
                    alert('checked');
                } else {
                    alert('unchecked');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then if you need to call a bean listener you can add two remoteCommands and call the functions in click callback

```
<p:pickList widgetVar="pick" showCheckbox="true" id="pickList"  value="#{ctrl.elts}" var="elt" itemLabel="#{elt}" itemValue="#{elts}" >
    <f:facet name="sourceCaption">A</f:facet>
    <f:facet name="targetCaption">B</f:facet>
</p:pickList>

<p:remoteCommand name="select" actionListener="#{ctrl.select}" />
<p:remoteCommand name="unselect" actionListener="#{ctrl.onUnselect}" />

<script>
    $(function(){
        PF('pick').checkboxes.each(function(){
            $(this).bind("click", function(){
                var checked = $(this).find("> span.ui-icon-check").length > 0
                if ( checked ){
                    select();
                } else {
                    unselect();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Obviously the listener can't accept a SelectEvent/UnselectEvent but with remoteCommand you can pass params if you need:

[Pass parameter to p:remoteCommand from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221495/pass-parameter-to-premotecommand-from-javascript)

Comment: So, why they added the Checkbox `showCheckbox="true"` if these events (select/unselect)  don't work. I think that there is a solution for that

Comment: I don't know why but there isn't a builtin way to what you want. The only thing that comes to my mind is to bind to click event of checkbox via js. I've updated the answer.