# Change Primefaces p:steps activeIndex with Javascript?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm considering using the `p:steps` component

```
<p:steps activeIndex="1" styleClass="custom" readonly="false">
    <p:menuitem value="Personal" url="#"/>
    <p:menuitem value="Seat Selection" url="#"/>
    <p:menuitem value="Payment" url="#"/>
    <p:menuitem value="Confirmation" url="#"/>
</p:steps>
```

how can I change activeIndex with Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Normally you should be able to do so using the JavaScript API and using the `widgetVar` attribute. However, when I use `widgetVar="stepsVar"`, the widget is unknown (JavaScript console):

```
> PF('stepsVar')
Widget for var 'stepsVar' not available!
```

So, you need some kind of workaround I'm afraid. For example, keep the index in a managed bean and update it using a [`remoteCommand`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml).

### XHTML

```xml
<p:remoteCommand name="setStepIndex"
                 action="#{yourBean.setStepIndexByRemoteCommand}"
                 update="steps"/>
<p:steps id="steps"
         activeIndex="#{yourBean.stepIndex}">
    <p:menuitem value="Personal" />
    <p:menuitem value="Seat Selection" />
    <p:menuitem value="Payment" />
    <p:menuitem value="Confirmation" />
</p:steps>
<button onclick="setStepIndex([{name:'index', value:2}]);return false">Test</button>
```

### Bean

```
private int stepIndex;

public int getStepIndex()
{
    return stepIndex;
}

public void setStepIndexByRemoteCommand()
{
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String, String> map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String indexString = map.get("index");
    stepIndex = Integer.valueOf(indexString);
}
```

### See also

- [Pass parameter to p:remoteCommand from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221495/pass-parameter-to-premotecommand-from-javascript)

Comment: I'd also found that widgetVar was undefined. Anyway,thanks I'll try your approach...

Comment: The steps component is not a 'widget' in the javascript sense. This can be seen in https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/steps/StepsRenderer.java. So it does not have a javascript api and is in that sense a 'readonly' component.

Comment: Thanks. I was about to report a bug. The `widgetVar` attribute is really misleading.

Comment: Another bug I ran into is binding the steps component. In that case duplicate IDs are generated.

Comment: Please do, it is misleading. I mentioned this before with the PF guys that their components do not throw an error if an unsupported attribute is used. And the 'interactive' version in the showcase does not do anything for me, so it seems like something is wrong (hmmm it does... just navigate to the current page)

Comment: Done. https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1690 and https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1691

Comment: @Kukeltje they closed it as invalid

Comment: you addition is good. Then please add 'documentation' and 'tagLib' to the title.

Comment: @Kukeltje Do you recon they read comments on closed issues? I guess they don't. Same thing seemed to have happened here https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1133

Comment: Thomas Andraschko at least does (if I remember correctly). Otherwise lets just spam them and create a new issue (but start it with a reference on why the other one was (invalidly, or to quickly) closed