# How to change tab in PrimeFaces onclick?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am programming in Java and xhtml, when I change of tab, jump to other place.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38912243/change-primefaces-psteps-activeindex-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You could use Primefaces Clinetside APi for `p:tabview` component.

Function Details:

```
select(index); 
selectTab(index) // Deprecated
```

Usage:

```
PF('TABVIEW_WIDGET_VAR').select(TABINDEX)
```