# valueChange event of primefaces ajax not triggered when the component's value is changed by a javascript function

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am surprised to see that the event valueChange does not trigger when the value of an inputText is changed by a javascript method.
However, it triggers when I manually change the value of the inputText.

You can test the code below to sense this, and maybe you can give a solution to make the event to trigger when a javascript function changes the value of a component.

The xhtml page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function testValueChange() {
        console.log("testValueChange called");
        var inputHCodes = document.getElementById('form:inptHCodes');
        inputHCodes.value = "new value";
      }
    </script>
    <h:form>
      <p:commandButton type="button" value="BUTTON" onclick="testValueChange();"/>

      <h:inputText id="inptHCodes" value="#{questionnaireExtendedKeyAttribute.selectedInputCodes}">
        <p:ajax event="valueChange" listener="#{questionnaireExtendedKeyAttribute.testValueChangeListener}"/> 
      </h:inputText>
    </h:form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The listener in backing bean:

```
public void testValueChangeListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent abe) {
   UIInput uiinput = (UIInput) abe.getSource();
   String id = uiinput.getId();
   selectedInputCodes = uiinput.getValue().toString();
   logger.debug("### value : " + selectedInputCodes + " and id is: " + id);
}
```

Comment: Does it work with f:ajax instead of p:ajax? If not, it is not PrimeFaces related (and I'm sure there is a duplicate of this Q in stackoverflow. If I remember correctly it is a html issue where this event is not triggered via javascript. Maybe fire it explicitly.

Comment: It doesn't work with f:ajax. How to fire it explicitly?

Comment: I am looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221495/pass-parameter-to-premotecommand-from-javascript, but I can't get it...

Comment: That question is not related. Look for jquery trigger()...

Comment: It is about triggering an ajax event, not jQuery. But I tried to trigger it explicitly and it does't work.

Comment: PrimeFaces components use jquery event handling to trigger sending ajax requests..but these are dom plain html components. Then see how you can 'trigger' those.. And how did you trigger it? But these are