# Prevent closing tab in p:tabView using Javascript

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, tabs, tabview

I need to prevent tab close in tabView primefaces and i know i can use

```
onTabClose="return false;"
```

The problem is I don't want to close tab but i want to make action when close is clicked. When i use `onTabClose="return false;"` then `<p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{bean.onTabClose}" update=":growls:mainGrowls"/>` is not called.

How can I prevent tab from closing on cross click and call function from bean?

Can i somehow prevent closing  in this method?

```
public void onTabClose(TabCloseEvent event) {       
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Tab Closed", "Closed tab: " + event.getTab().getId());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}
```

tabView:

```
<p:tabView id="tabView" activeIndex="0" style="height: 100%;" onTabClose="return false;">
            <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{bean.onTabClose}" update=":growls:mainGrowls"/>
            <p:tab title="#{tabTitle}" closable="false" >
                <div style="height: 100%; background: #efefef !important">
                    <ui:insert name="tab" />
                </div>
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="" closable="true" id="">

            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
```

Comment: Create a `p:remoteCommand`. Then use `onTabClose="yourRemoteCommand();return false;"`.

Comment: Thanks! One more question. In `onTabClose="return false;"` i can use also js `onTabClose="onTabClose(index);return false;"` which gives me index of closing tab. How can I pass this parameter to `p:remoteCommand`?

Comment: I found the solution: `onTabClose="tabClose(index);return false;"` then in javascript `function tabClose(i){
    tabCloseRc([{name: "index", value: i}]);` tabCloseRc is remoteCommand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to invoke a method in a managed bean, you could create a [`p:remoteCommand`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml):

```
<p:remoteCommand name="yourRemoteCommand"
                 actionListener="#{yourBean.yourMethod}" />
```

This allows you to use `yourRemoteCommand()` in Javascript, so you could use:

```
onTabClose="yourRemoteCommand(); return false;"
```

If you need to send parameters to the remote command, see:

- [Pass parameter to p:remoteCommand from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221495/pass-parameter-to-premotecommand-from-javascript)