# p:remoteCommand inside iterating component like p:dataTable only works for last row

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, remotecommand

i was trying to print the value entered in the inputText but it only shows 0 except for the last row it shows the right value!
here's a minimal code (i didn't include all the fields and the getters/setters)

```
@ManagedBean(name="medicament")
@ViewScoped
public class MedicamentBean {
  private List<Medicament> medicaments;
  private String libelle;
  private int qte_vente;

  public void test() {
    System.out.println(this.qte_vente);
}
}
```

html:

```
<h:form>
<p:dataTable value ="#{medicament.medicaments}" var ="m">
   <p:column headerText="libelle">      
      <h:outputText value = "#{m.libelle}"/>
   </p:column>
<p:column headerText="qte">
    <h:inputText value ="#{medicament.qte_vente}" onkeyup="myCommand();"/>
    <p:remoteCommand name="myCommand" actionListener="#{medicament.test()}"  style="display: none;" 
 />
   </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the webpage in webbrowser. Rightclick and choose *View Page Source*. Look carefully at the generated HTML output which you see there. When you have 10 table rows in e.g. `p:datatable`, it should look something like this

```
<table>
    <tr><td><script>function myCommand() { /* ... */ }</script></td></tr>
    <tr><td><script>function myCommand() { /* ... */ }</script></td></tr>
    <tr><td><script>function myCommand() { /* ... */ }</script></td></tr>
    <tr><td><script>function myCommand() { /* ... */ }</script></td></tr>
    <tr><td><script>function myCommand() { /* ... */ }</script></td></tr>
    <tr><td><script>function myCommand() { /* ... */ }</script></td></tr>
    <tr><td><script>function myCommand() { /* ... */ }</script></td></tr>
    <tr><td><script>function myCommand() { /* ... */ }</script></td></tr>
    <tr><td><script>function myCommand() { /* ... */ }</script></td></tr>
    <tr><td><script>function myCommand() { /* ... */ }</script></td></tr>
</table>
```

(When you use a different iterating component like a `p:datagrid` or even something like a `ui:repeat` it looks different but the generic 'repeating' is the same)

Guess which one gets invoked when you execute `myCommand()` in JavaScript ...

Right, that just doesn't work.

It would have worked with only one `<p:remoteCommand>` *outside* the `<p:dataTable>` to which you [pass a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221495/pass-parameter-to-premotecommand-from-javascript), which is a generic solution for all sorts of iterating components.

But in your case you are in fact overcomplicating things. Just use `<p:ajax>` instead.

```
<h:inputText ...>
    <p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{medicament.test()}" />
</h:inputText>
```

That's all.