# How to check which component called a primefaces remoteCommand?

Tags: javascript, primefaces, remotecommand

Is there a possibility (via primefaces or js or whatever) to check that my `p:remoteCommand` was called by a specific component and condition the action executed depending on that caller component ?

Comment: It's not called by a component but by Javascript

Comment: I mean the component that called the remoteCommand via js. For example : `<a href="#" onclick="myRemoteCommand()">here</a>`, in this case, I would like to capture that the caller was the `<a>` component.

Comment: Sure, use `this`

Comment: But I want to get the caller id from within the remoteCommand not the component

Comment: Just pass the caller ID as a parameter to your remoteCommand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221495/pass-parameter-to-premotecommand-from-javascript

Comment: @Melloware: you may mark questions as a duplicate if you think it is...

Comment: I usually don't have confidence to mark duplicate until someone else does. But I added my vote to your duplicate. :)