# How can I piggyback request arguments from a web socket message without manually constructing array?

Tags: jsf, websocket, primefaces, omnifaces

I've got an application scoped bean pushing json objects to a channel like this:

```xml
        <o:socket channel="controllerEventChannel" onmessage="function(message) {

                var controllerId = message.controllerId;
                var deviceId = message.deviceId;
                var companyKey = message.companyKey;

                onMessage([
                    { name: 'controllerId', value: controllerId },
                    { name: 'deviceId', value: deviceId },
                    { name: 'companyKey', value: companyKey }
                    ]);
        }"
        />

<p:remoteCommand name="onMessage" actionListener="#{controllerGroupDashboardBean.refreshListener()}"
                         update="MainForm:showList MainForm:equipmentView MainForm:mapEquipmentView"/>
```

But I'm tired of repeating myself and would much rather pass a json array to the channel which could be passed directly to the remote command like this:

```xml
        <o:socket channel="controllerEventChannel" onmessage="function(message) {
                onMessage(message);
        }"
        />

<p:remoteCommand name="onMessage" actionListener="#{controllerGroupDashboardBean.refreshListener()}"
                         update="MainForm:showList MainForm:equipmentView MainForm:mapEquipmentView"/>
```

However, this does not seem to work. I extract the parameters like this:

```java
Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        
String companyKey = params.get("companyKey");
String controllerId = params.get("controllerId");
String deviceId = params.get("deviceId");
```

Every parameter resolves to null and, weirdly, the map seems to contain the parameter "undefined" mapped to "" (i.e. blank string).

Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using OmniFaces commandScript for that, without any problems.

Edit:

To get request parameters, use OmniFaces for neater code:

```
String myParam = Faces.getRequestParameter("myJsonField", String.class);
```

Edit2:

```
<!-- When browser receive notification, this commandScript will be called -->
    <h:form id="myCommandScriptForm">
        <o:commandScript name="onNotification" actionListener="#{myBean.onNotification}" render="@none" />
    </h:form>
```

And in socket something like this:

```
<o:socket channel="my-channel" onmessage="function(notificationEvent) {onNotification(notificationEvent);}" />
```

In MyBean something like:

```
Long entityId = Faces.getRequestParameter("entityId", Long.class);
```

If you wanna be fancy you can update from MyBean (notice i have render="@none" in XHTML, this is because i can conditionaly determine what to update in bean):

```
public void onNotification() {
    if (myList.contains(myEntity)) {
        PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update(":myWrapperJsfElement");
    }
}
```

OP ADDENDUM: o:commandScript was removed from OmniFaces after it was added in JSF 2.3.

Comment: This looks like what Im trying to do except with OmniFaces CommandScript. Isn't that tag functionally the same as PrimeFaces RemoteCommand? I will try it tomorrow and get back to you. Thanks! Oh, and what do you pass to the pushcontext?

Comment: This is indeed the way. See also "UI update design hints" section of `<o:socket>` documentation: https://showcase.omnifaces.org/push/socket#ui. The issue with `<p:remoteCommand>` is that it doesn't support taking parameters as a `Map<K, V>` but basically only as a `List<Map.Entry<K, V>>`. They do so in order to support multiple parameter values by the same name, which isn't possible with a `Map<K, V>`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/18510102

Comment: So, theoretically, if you want to keep using `<p:remoteCommand>`, then you have got to push the data in `List<Map.Entry<K, V>>` format instead of `Map<K, V>`. But of course, the `<o:commandScript>` is more fit for your specific situation ;)

Comment: I'm using OmniFaces push, not PrimeFaces. As BalusC said, showcase explains it in detail. Works realy nice. I'm pushing POJOs, they're transformed to JSON under the OmniFaces hood.

Comment: PrimeFaces Push is removed in PF 6.3 so if you have time, migrate to OmniFaces.

Comment: Well, it sure took some time before I got to circle back to this. I'm now stuck using o:commandScript. It says: 

jakarta.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object: org.omnifaces.component.script.CommandScript not found.

I tried updating from 4.1 to 4.2 but no change. I've checked that metadata-complete is not toggled on in faces-config. This is a simple Java 17 WAR project deployed using standard Tomcat 10.1.

Comment: Hmmm... I can't find commandscript in the current OmniFaces showcase at all and neither in the JAR. It's in the tag lib though.

Comment: OH! It's been removed because h:commandScript now can replace it. The plot thickens!